# SQL-запрос выбора записи по номеру

Tags: jdbc, java, sql

Здравствуйте, форумчане.

Помогите, кто может, составить студенту sql запрос выбора записи таблицы по его номеру. Запрос (составлен мной) выглядит так:

```
try
{
    String sqlReqest = "select * from "+strTableName+" where id = [3,5,7]";    
    statement.executeUpdate(sqlReqest);

    // SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = [2, 5, 11]
}
catch(Exception ex)
```

Возвращает постоянно ошибку: слишком мало параметров требуется 2. Когда в параметрах указываю один номер без [], то ошибка: слишком мало параметров требуется 1. Подскажите мне правильную запись запроса.

Есть какая-то возможность определить число записей в таблице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый день вижу что-то новое) Пните меня сильно, если так как сверху написанно вообще можно делать.

id - это не "номер записи".
Это (принято, но не обязательно) уникальный код записи в таблице.

Во-вторых нигде не сказано, что он сплошной.
Было 1,2,3,4. 2 удалили и стало 1,3,4. 
И в общем-то восстанавливать такое не рекомендуется.

Вариантов два. Либо на клиенте пропускать нужно число записей, либо использовать что-то типа конструкции limit в mysql. Но она работает только на интервал.

Если вам нужна выборка по id, то:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id in (2, 5, 11)
```

Comment: На процедуру передается номер записи (из возможного диапазона) и эта процедура должна представить пользователю на экран значение этой записи. Вот как сформулировать запрос, я не могу понять ...

 private void ShowCurrentTableRecord(int RecordNumber)
 {
  if (bCreatedConnection)
  {
   try
   {
    String sqlReqest = "SELECT * FROM "+strTableName+" WHERE id IN (1)";
    
    statement.executeUpdate(sqlReqest);
    
    tfQuestionText.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
    tfFirstAnswer.setText(resultSet.getString(2));
    ...
   }

Comment: Бррр....

    String sqlReqest = "SELECT * FROM "+strTableName+" WHERE id IN (" + RecordNumber + ")";

?

Вообще, в вопрос-ответ спользуют обычтно такую конструкцию:

     select 
         Вопрос.*,
         Ответ.* 
       from мояТаблицаВопросов as Вопрос

       left join мояТаблицаОтветов as Ответ 
            on Ответ.IDвопроса = Вопрос.ID

       where 
            Вопрос.ID = IDВопроса

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (2, 5, 11);

SELECT COUNT(id) FROM mytable;
```